# After logout previous captured request still valid in azure ad authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, logout

We are facing issue on logout from our application. Once we logout then its perfectly fine from browser but if we capture the request from some tools (fidler or burp) and send the request again to server with old cookies and session details give full response. This is only possible through any interceptor tool only. I am using the below code to logout from application:

```
Session.RemoveAll();            
 HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
               CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because `access token` and `refresh tokens` issued by Azure AD are not deleted when you initiate the log out from your application. As long as these tokens have not expired, they can be used.

Based on [`this`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/12717), access token lifetime is configurable (default I believe is 1 hour) and you should set it based on your needs.

Also, there's a feedback post regarding invalidating tokens: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/19474918-invalidate-jwt-token. Feel free to upvote this feature.

Comment: Thanks @gaurav Since i am using azure ad authentication (microsoft login page) and we are not using any other explicit jwt token and on logout application is getting redirected on the  https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tanant id}/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={logouturl}  and its working perfectly from browser side but if we again hit the old request from fidler or some tool then it gets authenticated.

Comment: If you take a look at the request, you’ll see ‘Authorization’ header that contains the access token.

Comment: I got the your point but in my scenario the the above code automatically takes back to logout url perfectly but in server side it is still valid :(

Comment: The link to the feedback post is dead.